# Android Studio Push Commits - Add Remote

Tags: android, android-studio, mercurial, push

How can I enter a Remote in Android Studios Push Commit window?

I see the text "Enter Remote", but I can't edit it.

So how can I enter a remote?
I am using Android Studio 1.2.2

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press **Enter** key over library that doesn't have remote. After that you should be able to add URL in field.

Comment: Oh my goodness!!!! Shame over me... I have made a click and a double click, but not ENTER :-) Thanks!

Comment: Yes of course but I have to wait a few minutes. Otherwise it is not working.

Comment: Is this possible to save the repo URL so you don't have to type it in everytime you push?